# jQuery Sortable todo List

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to build a todo list.  http://d2burke.com/exp/todo/

I want my user to be able to mark items as complete, at which point the item is dropped down to the 'Complete' list, and vice versa.  I also want each of these lists to be independently sortable.

I'm using a basic custom method to move the items back and forth, and I've used jQueryUI Sortable to sort them.

All of these things I've been able to accomplish; however, it doesn't seem as though the site (the DOM?) is registering that the items were moved from one list to the other.  If I mark one item as 'Complete' it physically moves down...and becomes sortable in the 'Complete' list, but  I'm echoing out the current positions in serialized format (because I'm going to record the order in a db) and the app doesn't seem to recognize that the item has moved.

I'd like to force the app to recalculate the list of items when an item is marked complete, or incomplete.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

I looks to me like you should look at the resfresh methods of of the sortable: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

I would start with .refresh() too see if that also recalculates the positions. I assume it does but if not you might need to trigger the other one too.

Comment: well, i've tried this, a combination of ways...refresh, refreshPositons, unbind() then refresh...all to no avail.  Thanks for the idea though...I was sure that was going to be the ticket

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that stand out that I would comment on:-

1) When you 'move' an item, you are moving more than you intend - the moved item has a 'tbody' around it - your code is very fragile, depending on parent.parent... which will be a nightmare to maintain.

2) You have various parent.parent constructs - lose these switch to '.closest()' to search up the tree to the class of item you wan to operate on.

3) You are doing things with binding/unbinding - lose them and switch to '$(document.body).on(,...)' then jquery will add/remove events automatically based on your selector - link once and forget.

Once this is done the bugs may go away - if not it will still be clearer so possible to debug properly!

Regards

ps. If it were me, I think I'd link the two list so they are sortable together, and toggle the completed flag if an item is moved from one list to the other.

This way the user has two ways of changing the status and jquery will do all the donkey work as you are simply sorting a normal linked list.